# Возможен ли такой диалог? Смущает слово «бывает»? Или это нормально?

Tags: разговорная-речь

Собеседник говорит: Не видел, родной.

Я отвечаю ему: Бывает

Comment: Николай, напишите поточнее, что вызывает трудности: возможен ли такой диалог? его оформление на письме? а может, и то и другое?

Comment: Тогда напишите, что смущает в этом диалоге.

Comment: А в чем смущение то? Реплика: Не заметил, родной. Ответ: У всех такое иногда случается (бывает).

Answer (score 3):

Такой диалог совершенно "нормален".

Из статьи [**БЫВАЕТ**, *вводное слово*](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_75) (Грамота.ру):

> **! Не смешивать** с употреблением в роли члена предложения (сказуемого).
> *Я не хочу судьею быть, // Не все разлуку побеждают, // Не все способны век любить, – // К несчастью, в жизни всё **бывает.*** К. Симонов, Открытое письмо.

Из статьи [**БЫВАТЬ**](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C&all=x) (Грамота.ру, Большой толковый словарь):

> □**безл.** *Бывает, что и не спится. Со мной тоже так бывает.*

[**Безличные предложения**](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F) (Википедия):

> Главный член или члены могут быть выражены
> формой 3-го лица единственного числа безличного или личного глагола: *Светает!*

В речи мы часто опускаем понятные из контекста слова:

***— Не видел, родной.***
***—*** [И такое] ***бывает.***

Вторая реплика — это неполное предложение.

[**Полные и неполные предложения**](https://rustutors.ru/russkiy/syntaxis/2308-polnye-i-nepolnye-predlozhenija.html) (РУСТЬЮТОРС):

> **Функции неполных предложений:**
> • помогают избежать тавтологии;
> • облегчают речь;
> • делают проще конструкции сложных предложений.